# ELK : how to process data from 2 lines?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

On our web application, we have logs at the start and at the end of method like this :

```
2015-07-10 11:06:06,571 [INFO ][http-apr-80-exec-60] IDeviseService - Method findChangeForDate - Start by : bokc
2015-07-10 11:06:06,571 [INFO ][http-apr-80-exec-60] IDeviseService - Method findChangeForDate - End
```

I "split" this into different tags (methodName : findChangeForDate , user : bokc, time: 2015-07-10 11:06:06,571, thread :http-apr-80-exec-60,....).

But is it possible with ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana) to find the execution delay or may I have to add this information directly on the log?

BokC

Answer (score 0):

The [elapsed{} filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html) can compute the difference between your 'start' and 'stop' events.  You add tags for the start/end events, and then use elapsed{} to correlate them.

```
  elapsed {
    start_tag => "myStartTag"
    end_tag => "myEndTag"
    unique_id_field => "myCorrelatingField"
    timeout => 300
    new_event_on_match => false
  }
```

Comment: It look like what I need. Tanks.